# User Alerts are not working

Tags: 2016, alert

I created a SharePoint Alert on a custom list which sends out notifications Immediately for all the changes.

- Outbound Email settings are configured in central administration.
- Custom notifications are also working, which are sent out using workflows.

Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Did it worked previously..?If so wait at least 15 min...

Comment: It is a new environment

Comment: Alright, If your waited for 15 min and If you are in on-prem and have access to Central Admin check the  "ImmediateAlert" Timer job and it status...

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint sends `SPAlerts` via scheduled TimerJobs

> - Immediate Alerts
> - Daily Alerts
> - Weekly Alerts

Since you ensured `Outbound Email settings` is already configured in central admin. And for `Immediate Alerts` wait for `15 min` and check you received email if not check the above Job status and interval.